# Countdown timer multiple item

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using this package called [react-countdown-now](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-countdown-now) I have many items I'm just wondering why all the items counting down same time

https://codesandbox.io/s/4rpn84j5m0

As you can see below in my example the new item rest the old item

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Countdown from 'react-countdown-now';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      show: false
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ show: true })
    }, 2500)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      
        <Countdown date={Date.now() + 10000} /><br />
        {this.state.show ? <Countdown date={Date.now() + 10000} /> : <span>waiting new item....</span>}
        <p>
        Why the new item rest the old item?
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Why the new item rest the old item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because the expression `Date.now() + 10000` gets recalculated on every re-render / state update. You need to store the dates somewhere.

**As an example:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/zq1mv4zmz4

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Countdown from "react-countdown-now";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      dates: [Date.now() + 10000]
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ show: true });
    }, 2500);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.dates.map(date => (
          <div>
            <Countdown date={date} />
          </div>
        ))}
        <button onClick={() => this.addDate()}>New Item</button>
        <p>Why the new item rest the old item?</p>
      </div>
    );
  }

  addDate() {
    let dates = [...this.state.dates, Date.now() + 10000];
    this.setState({ dates });
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```